# How to distinguish a 1N4148 diode from a Zener diode visually?

Tags: diodes, zener

The 1N4148 looks like this and a Zener diode looks the same.

What is the most recommended way to distinguish or identify them visually?

[image]

Comment: Close voter, how is this opinion based?

Comment: @Passerby, of course any answer would be opinion-based, hence my VTC. 'Looks the same' is subjective and there are loads of parts involved made by multiple manufacturers. No-one here's going to cross-reference them all and give a definitive answer. As reflected in the answers given, including your one.

Comment: The basic trick here is don't mix them up. Just like surface mount capacitors, once removed from their packaging and emptied on a desk they instantly become useless if mixed with other SMD capacitors. It's all about quality and common sense.

Comment: Classification with the use of a box with multiple lockers when one receive it?

Comment: the 1N4148 IS a Zener diode at 75V https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/microchip-technology/JANTXV1N4148-1/7606835  So your question ought to be how do you read codes to find the specs

Comment: As I understand from your feedback, a best practice would be to "purchase", "label" and keep them "separately" in boxes. (eventually double check on usage)

Comment: When I was OPs Mgr for a small company of 50 people we could make 10 quick turn PCB's for the designers same day.  I used 35 mm film bins for the SMD and THT parts labelled in bin #s and the stock pick parts list would also list the same #. Then I had made arrays of more than 50 35 mm film containers glued to a tray.

Comment: 4148's often have yellow, brown, yellow, grey stripes on them.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Well... is the 75V rating on them based on the Zener effect or the avalanche effect?

Comment: Anything >> 5V (reverse)  is usually the avalanche effect with similar results.  You could submit a correction to Digikey's wording, not AVX or ON.  But then ""such quibbling over semantics may seem like petty stuff"

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/601273/understanding-flyback-power-supply-with-weird-snubber-circuit-and-general-funct "The LL4148 is being used as a zener diode"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's a standard package for many diodes.

The only way to distinguish them visually is by any printed code. Or to buy them in labeled packaging from the trusted seller (digikey, mouser, the manufacturer) and don't mix them up.

Electrically you can measure the diode and put it through a few tests to get some general specs and type but trying to nail down the model would be difficult based on the sheer number of similar parts. Professionals wouldn't waste their time and hobbyists shouldn't either. The miniaturization and mass production of these commodity parts prevent that type of reuse. Just buy new ones that are properly labeled.

Answer (score 3):

There is no reliable way to distinguish between them visually, as they look the same.

However, there is an easy, reliable way of making the distinction without having to look up the manufacturer code:

Reverse bias the diode with a power supply and a high value resistor to limit current, and then measure the voltage across it.

Comment: Wouldn't necessarily work, either, if you have some high-voltage zeners. A 1N4148 will avalanche around 70 to 80 volts or so, and if you have zeners it could get mixed up with in that range you may not be able to tell the difference for sure.

Answer (score 2):

They are typically marked.

For example, [Onsemi's](https://rocelec.widen.net/view/pdf/bhc41r7lwc/ONSM-S-A0003539415-1.pdf?t.download=true&u=5oefqw) 1N4148 are marked "4148" with a black cathode band.

[Onsemi's](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Fairchild%20PDFs/1N746A-759A,4370A-4372A.pdf)(Fairchild) 1N751 (5.1V Zener) are marked [logo], 51, A

Unfortunately, the similar SMT Mini-MELF package (eg. LL4148) is seldom marked and  you just have to keep track of them.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you can tell because a 1N4148 is typically marked '1N4148' on the body, while a Zener diode has a different marking. You may need a magnifying glass to make sure though, because other diodes can have quite similar markings. If the markings are partially rubbed off it might be difficult to tell the difference.

Typical DO35 package Zener markings are eg. '1N4135' (a 100 V 500 mW Zener) or 'C18' (BZX55C18 18 V 500 mW Zener). Sometimes just the voltage is marked, eg '18' for 18 volts.

One thing you should **not** do is trust the images shown on websites. Here's a snapshot from the product page of a 1N4148 from [Digikey](https://www.digikey.co.nz/en/products/detail/micro-commercial-co/1N4148-TP/773645). Note the disclaimer "Image shown is a representation only. Exact specifications should be obtained from the product data sheet."

[image]

And here's an "18v Zener" from [electroniccenter.co.uk](https://electroniccentre.co.uk/18v-zener). It appears to  be identical to Digikey's image rotated 180°, and the filename was '1n4148-29__78472.jpg'!

[image]