# How to drive base of an NPN with a reverse-connected diode?

Tags: circuit-analysis, reverse-engineering

The circuit schematic belongs to controller board of a some kind of heater device. I reverse engineered it from the board itself and checked it three times. Its function is so simple: You adjust duration; during that time device is supposed to provide 220VAC to its outputs. When the time finishes, it stops output of 220VAC. As I understand from the circuit, timing is set by `pot`, `R3`, and `C4`. But in particular, `D6` diode confused me a lot. Also `D5` is somewhat fishy according to my current knowledge.

Have you ever seen such a driving circuit and if so I'd appreciate if you could explain how the circuit works? What are `D5` and `D6` for?

[image]

Comment: D5 and D6 are likely [Zener diodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zener_diode), which are designed to conduct at a controlled voltage in the reverse direction.  D6 for example, is designed to drop a fairly large voltage so all of that voltage isn't dropped by the resistor below it.

Comment: D5 is likely a normal diode that is sued to discharge C4 so that if there's a power loss, the charging for C4 begins from 0 volts.

Comment: Related https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/601273/understanding-flyback-power-supply-with-weird-snubber-circuit-and-general-funct

Comment: Yep i checked again and the D6 is 1n4547 ; a zener diode of 16volts.